# Why is Apache ignoring my rewrite rule?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have an old application with URLs of the form...

```
http://apps.myserver.com/appname/viewItem.akt?p=123
```

I am replacing this old app with one that has URLs like...

```
http://appname.myserver.com/item/123
```

I've tried adding several different rewrite rules to `httpd/httpd.conf` and restarting the server, but I keep getting 404 errors.

A couple things I've tried...

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^.*viewItem.akt\?p=([0-9]*)$ http://appname.myserver.com/item/$1 [R]
```

Or...

```
RewriteRule ^/appname/viewItem.akt\?p=([0-9]*)$ http://appname.myserver.com/item/$1 [R]
```

The result is always "The requested URL /appname/viewItem.akt was not found on this server", as if the rewrite rule weren't even there.

What I'm getting in the access log is...

```
[IP address] - - [09/Sep/2011:21:27:37 -0700] "GET /appname/viewItem.akt?p=1018 HTTP/1.0" 404 248
```

I tested all my regexes in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to make sure they match the incoming request.

What am I missing?

---

In case it's relevant, the old application was a Java app running under Tomcat, and I had a ProxyPass set up like this...

(I'm showing these lines commented out, as they are when I'm trying to get the rewrite rule to work.)

```
# ProxyPass /appname http://apps.myserver.com:8080/appname
# ProxyPassReverse /appname http://apps.myserver.com:8080/appname
```

But that shouldn't matter right? As long as my rewrite rule matches the request it should send it along properly, shouldn't it?

Comment: Error logs and rewrite logs would be instructive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^appname/viewItem.akt$ http://appname.myserver.com/item/%1? [R,L]
```

- `%1` to back reference to Rewrite Condition
- `?` at the end of substitution to remove the rest of query string

But it seems you are mixing up `mod_rewrite` with `mod_proxy`. Which Apache version are you running?

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I only mentioned the Proxy settings because they relate to the previous app that I'm trying to decommission on the off chance that they're relevant somehow. They are commented out.

Comment: Apache version is 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `mod_rewrite` is correctly loaded?

Otherwise, using the directive [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) with an according [RewriteLogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel) should help you figuring out if your RewriteRule is taken into account while requesting your page, and if the regular expression matches or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this suits your need, but these things drive me crazy too. I always try to simplify as much as I can.

This appears to work in my tests:
 `RewriteRule p=([0-9]*)$ http://appname.myserver.com/item/$1`